# Regex: find several patterns inside brackets

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract from source code certain information in square brackets (key and value).
Example of text:

```
    "analytics": [
        ["KEY", "BLA BLA"],["KEY2","BLA BLA"],
        ["KEY3", "BLA BLA"]
    ]
    [BAD STRING]
```

I want to get list of strings with certain pattern: ["KEY","Value"], not everything in [], so I can't use `\[(.*?)\]` 
I tried `\[(\"\S+\"\,\s*\".*\")\]` and it works good for key-value on separate line, but takes everything between [] on one line.
Looking for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
\["([^"]*)"\s*,\s*"([^"]*)"]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZb4ST/5)

**Details**:

- `\["` - a `["` substring
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a double quote
- `\s*,\s*` - a `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `"` - a double quote
- `([^"]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"]` - a double quote and then `]`.

Comment: @howlger Do not use possessive quantifiers where they do not really bring any performance boost. Here, the non-possessive, greedy quantifiers are "performant" enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot! exactly what I need!